# Como imitar comando "até que... faça" com o python?

Tags: python, loop, linha-de-comando

Como eu posso fazer um contador regredindo com o python?

Eu tentei assim:

---

```
count = int(10)  
    while True:  
        print("Eu conto", count)  
        count = int(count -1)
        if count = 0:  
            break
```

---

mas parece que ele não aceita o -1. Como eu poderia fazer isso funcionar?

Comment: O operador de comparação é o `==`, o operador `=` é o operador de atribuição. Use: `if count == 0:` .

Comment: Ah, é verdade, obrigado!

Comment: Também não é necessário informar que o número 10 é do tipo int poque o Python já sabe. Se quiser você pode retira-lo.

Comment: Eu imaginei que não precisaria, mas tava dando erro dai acabei colocando.

Comment: Porque usou a função int() se os numeros já são inteiros?

Comment: Por que não colocar a comparação no `while`? Retiraria o `if` e o `break` dentro dele

Comment: É que eu tava tentando encontrar uma função que fizesse a checagem só depois da execução do código.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar o o `for` para isso, colocarei um exemplo abaixo.

```
for count in range(10, -1, -1):
    print("Eu conto", count)
```

é bem simples

além disso você pode acrescentar o time, irei da um exemplo abaixo

```
import time

for count in range(10, -1, -1):
    print("Eu conto", count)
    time.sleep(1)
```

fazendo assim que espere 1 segundo a cada vez que contar um numero

e outro jeito reduzindo para uma linha seria assim

```
print(*[f'Eu conto {count}' for count in range(10, -1, -1)], sep='\n')
```

ai é só escolher o que mais satisfaz e fazer as suas modificações

---

### Explicando a questão do range para o melhor entendimento

o range te da uma função geradora que itera de acordo com as variáveis passadas, podendo ser somente o stop, por exemplo `range(10)` conta do 0 ao 9, lembrando que não vai até o fim, ou podemos informar os números que ira começar (start), parar (stop) e quando números ele vai pulando, por exemplo `range(2, 20, 5)` ele ira começar a contar do numero 2 e finalizar no numero 20, porém ele vai pulando de 5 em 5 te dando um resultado igual a `[2, 7, 12, 17]`

espero que tenha conseguido explicar um pouco.

Comment: Não conhecia esse. Muito obrigado!

Comment: há mais opções mas creio que essa seja a mais simples pra entender, mas qualquer duvida é só dizer, vou acrescentar mais um jeito, só 1 min